# Question on the normality assumption of the predictor variable and the covariance matrix of the likelihood

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, covariance-matrix

Suppose you are trying to fit a continuous variable y depending on some input x ( es y= ax+b) and you are using a multivariate distribution as likelihood for the fitting.

Does using a multinormal distribution  with a non diagonal covariance matrix as likelihood  means necessarily that  the target variable y is not normally distributed around its true value ? in other words, the assumption that the predictive uncertainty is gaussian is still valid?

Comment: Do you mean the distribution of $(Y\vert X=x)$ when $(X,Y)\sim N((\mu_X, \mu_Y), \Sigma)$ for non-diagonal covariance matrix $\Sigma?$ [That distribution is Gaussian, yes.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/392664/247274)

Comment: JFYI: non-zero off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix simply [imply correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/608699). Nothing more and nothing less.